# How to fix 'Cannot use geometry manager grid inside . which already has slaves managed by pack'

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

I am new to Tkinter, and am trying to create a window that has a button that opens another window when clicked. When trying to open the new window, I get the above error. I understand that pack() and grid() cannot be used together, but that leads to more confusion.

In my main window, I tried removing the self.pack line, but nothing would show up in my main window. After removing it, I tried calling self.grid, and everything showed up but was not in the proper positions (they were all jammed together in the top left corner). What I think is happening is the self.pack line is causing issues in the new window, but I'm not sure if that is what is causing the issue. If it is, I don't understand why.

Here is the main window

```
class Window(Frame):
    #constructor
    def __init__(self,master = None):
        Frame.__init__(self,master)
        self.master = master

        self.init_window()

    #create the window
    def init_window(self):
        self.master.title("Japanese Word A Day")

        #configure the grid
        self.columnconfigure(1,weight=1)
        self.rowconfigure(1,weight=1)

        #configure the view history button
        view_button = Button(self, text="View\nSaved Words", command=self.view_history)
        view_button.grid(column=3,row=5)

        #fill the window - without this line, nothing shows up
        self.pack(fill=BOTH, expand=1)

    def view_history(self):
        self.h_window = Toplevel(self.master)
        history = History(self.h_window)
```

Here is the new window

```
class History(Frame):
    def __init__(self,master):
        Frame.__init__(self,master)
        self.master = master
        self.init_window()

    def init_window(self):
        self.master.title("Japanese Word A Day - History")
        self.master.geometry("600x600")

        headers = ("English","Kanji","Kana","Romaji","Pronunciation")
        self.tree = ttk.Treeview(columns=headers,show="headings")

        self.y_scroll = ttk.Scrollbar(orient=VERTICAL,command=self.tree.yview)
        self.tree['yscroll'] = self.y_scroll.set

        self.rowconfigure(0,weight=1)
        self.columnconfigure(0,weight=1)

        self.tree.grid(row=0,column=0,sticky=NSEW)
        self.y_scroll.grid(row=0, column=1,sticky=NS)
```

Here is the code that instantiates the main window

```
root = Tk()
root.geometry("400x300")
app = Window(root)
root.mainloop()
```

This is in Python 3.6.8. Looking at examples of the grid manager online, I have seen some programs include the pack, and others that do not.

Comment: You have not posted a [mcve]; in particular, you have not posted the code that instantiates `Window()`.  That class is definitely broken, in that it does not supply the `master` parameter to `Frame.__init__()`, so you have no control over who its parent is.

Comment: @jasonharper Thank you for your response. I added the code that instantiates Window() and (hopefully) fixed the class. I was experimenting while trying to debug and forgot to change it back. It is now back to it's original code

Comment: Aha, I see the problem now - you are failing to provide the `master` parameter for your `Treeview` and `Scrollbar`, so they are implicitly becoming children of the root window, NOT the History window.  You're calling `.grid()` on them, but the one proper child of the root window was `.pack()`ed, thus the error.

Comment: @jasonharper Thank you, that did the trick! Setting the master to self allowed both widgets to be visible, and there was no error.